# Jquery Ajax 401 response using Twitter API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, twitter

We are using postman to send the request with the proper parameter of Authorization and our access key which returns the JSON we are looking for, however in our javascript we are trying to send a request using ajax and jsonp but are getting a 401 response error when attempting to do so. Here is our code.

```
shopButton.click(() => {
            // The getJSON function initiates a connection to the web service.
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=adidasalerts&count=3',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                headers: {
                    'Authorization':'Bearer REDACTED',
                }
                success: function(dataWeGotViaJsonp){
                    console.log(dataWeGotViaJsonp)
                }
            });
        });
```

We know our access token works because we can send requests just fine using Postman. Does anyone have any ideas? Before we were attempting to use $.getJSON but we kept getting cross origin domain errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery ajax doesn't understand what you mean by the property `Authorization` - you need to add the Authorization header using the `headers` property or the `beforeSend` callback to set the header - see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {Authorization: 'Bearer REDACTED'},
    url: 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=adidasalerts&count=3',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function (dataWeGotViaJsonp) {
        console.log(dataWeGotViaJsonp)
    }
});
```

Comment: we tried adding a headers property but our call still does not work. looking around it seems that its impossible. I've updated our code with what we tried. Postman still works however with the same header.

Comment: I don't understand the comment

Comment: sorry the comment saved before I finished editing. check again.

Comment: are you sure you need to use jsonp - do you get a CORS error with using json? (not $.getJSON, but dataType: 'json')

Comment: yes before we tried an ajax approach we were using $.getJSON but were getting CORS errors. Should we try switching back to $.getJSON?

Comment: no, I said don't use getJSON, I said try using dataType: 'json' - but if that gives a CORS error, then you have to use jsonp ... or a server side solution

Comment: We'll try that. If that doesn't work for the server side solution what would that entail? Do you have any links we could take a look at for pursuing a server side solution. Thank you.

Comment: server side solution would require server side code - as I'm not aware of your server side environment, that's as good an answer as I can give